# a == b returns true, a.attribute == b.attribute returns false; ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm testing this line of a controller:

```
@channel.update_attribute(:active, true)

expect(channel.active).to be_true fails (my variable is named 'channel')
expect(assigns[:channel].active).to be_true passes

assigns[:channel] == channel
=> true

assigns[:channel].active == channel.active
=> false

assigns[:channel].active == channel.reload.active
=> true
```

I don't understand why the comparison operator says that assigns[:channel] == channel, but that their "active" attribute is different.

Comment: It seems to work if you call `channel.reload` (last expression). This means that `channel` and `@channel` are different objects. Updating one doesn't automatically update the other, although they might refer to the same record in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose a channel is an ActiveRecord object and it's the same as doing:

```
channel1 = Channel.find(1)
channel2 = Channel.find(1)
```

So `channel1 == channel2` because their identity is the same. (they are both channels and have the same id)

But if you update one of them, the other will be stale.

```
channel1.active = "different value"
channel1.save
channel1.active != channel2.active
```

Doing `channel2.reload` will fetch the attributes from the database and now

```
channel1.active == channel2.active
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-3D-3D

Comment: I added a reference to the docs that was sent to me by Yi Wen

Answer (score 2):

Because equality for ActiveRecord models is based on their ID, not every attribute.  So it is the same model, they just have a different settings for their "active" attribute.  That's why it works after you reload.

I think it might work like you expect if you change the first line:

`@channel.update(active: true)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what *exactly* is happening in your specific situation, but the general situation is not at all strange:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize
    @bar = Bar.new
  end

  def ==(*) true end

  class Bar
    def ==(*) false end
  end
end

a = Foo.new
b = Foo.new

a == b
# => true

a.bar == b.bar
# => false
```

This is just a consequence of object-oriented encapsulation. It is up to `a` to decide whether or not it thinks it is equal to `b`, and it is up to `a.bar` to decide whether or not it thinks it is equal to `b.bar`, and there is nothing to enforce that the two have to agree.

In your case, there seems to be some caching consistency issue. You seem to have two different objects that both represent the same database record, and one of them has stale data.